# How to concat two dataframes in which one is having record and other one is empty in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I need help to concat two dataframes in which one is empty and other one having the data. Could you please how to do this in pyspark?

pandas I am using:

suppose df2 is empty and df1 is having some record.

```
df2 = pd.concat([df2, df1])
```

But how to perform this operation in pyspark?

```
df1:

+--------------------+----------+---------+
|         Programname|Projectnum|     Drug|
+--------------------+----------+---------+
|Non-Oncology Phar...|SR0480-000|Invokamet|
+--------------------+----------+---------+

df2:

++
||
++
++
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `df2 = df1`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried many option. One option worked for me.

For concat df2 to df1, first I need to create the structure of df2 same like df1 then use the `union` for concatanation.

```
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), df1.schema)
df2 = df2.union(df1)

result:

df2:
+--------------------+----------+---------+
|         Programname|Projectnum|     Drug|
+--------------------+----------+---------+
|Non-Oncology Phar...|SR0480-000|Invokamet|
+--------------------+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [union](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union) method:

```
df = df1.union(df2)
```

Comment: doesn't work because the two dataframes have different number of columns

Comment: In Spark you only can do this operation with union, so you can create the columns with null values